# Find the number of incongruent solutions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, hensels-lemma

Let $p$ be a prime number. Find the number of incongruent solutions of 
$$ x^{p^5}-x+p\equiv0\mod p^{2020}.$$

---

Let $f(x) = x^{p^5}-x+p$. Because of $f '(x)$ different from zero mod $p$. Then I say
$$f(x) \equiv 0\mod p \quad(1) $$
and 
$$ f(x) \equiv0\mod p^k $$
are the same.

Then I calculate (1) equation. But in this part I'm not sure. For $x=0$ and $x=p$ it is true. But is there something else? How can I sure about it.

Comment: If you want to use Hensel's lemma here to find number of solutions to $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^k}$, you need to know the number of solutions to $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod p$. Clearly, $x =0, p$ are solutions to the latter. Now, what else are solutions?

Comment: Okey I've solved (1) equation. It is come true for all x. So there is p solution I guess.

Comment: Exactly, so Hensel's Lemma tells us that there are exactly $p$ solutions to the latter congruence equation as well.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = x^{p^5}-x+p$. Observe that $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod p$ has exactly $p$ solutions. Moreover, 
$$f'(x) \equiv -1 \not\equiv 0 \pmod p,$$ 
for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, by Hensel's Lemma, each of these $p$ solutions can be lifted uniquely to a root modulo $p^2, p^3, \ldots, p^{2020}$. Accordingly, the congruence equation $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^{2020}}$ has $p$ unique incongruent solutions.